# Connecting to an embedded neo4j database as a remote database

Tags: neo4j

I have a Spring boot project in Kotlin using Neo4j 3.3.5 as an embedded database.
The database is tested to be accessible (read-write). 
I now want to access the database as a remote database using neo4j desktop 1.0.24, in order to view the nodes graphically and maybe add my own externally.

I currently access the database using:

```
private val curdir = System.getProperty("user.dir")
val graphDb: GraphDatabaseService = GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(File("${curdir}/database"))
```

The most recent guide I found to achieve what I need is [this](https://graphaware.com/neo4j/2015/02/10/neo4j-shell-with-embedded.html).

In short the configuration provided in the guide above is:

```
GraphDatabaseService db = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(DB_DIR)
                .setConfig(ShellSettings.remote_shell_enabled, "true")
                .setConfig(ShellSettings.remote_shell_port, "5555")
                .newGraphDatabase();
```

which however does not seem to work (unresolved reference ShellSettings).

After some search in the current (3.3) documentation I found that `setConfig` comes in 3 flavours two of which are deprecated:

```
setConfig(Map<String,String> config) // deprecated
setConfig(String name, String value) // deprecated

setConfig(Setting<?> setting, String value)
```

The last option is not, but the `interface Setting<T>` itself, is pending reconstruction and is also deprecated.

Attempting to use setConfig like this for example:

```
    var graphDb = GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(File("${curdir}/database"))
        .setConfig("remote_shell_enabled", "true")
        .setConfig("remote_shell_port", "5555")
        .newGraphDatabase()
```

though works for Spring, is not accessible from neo4j Desktop with configurations:

```
Database Name: Database
Host: localhost
Bolt Port: 5555
username: blank
password: blank
```

What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

The desktop is not using `shell` but the `bolt protocol`.
So youneed to enable it in the configuration :

```
GraphDatabaseSettings.BoltConnector bolt = GraphDatabaseSettings.boltConnector( "0" );

GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
        .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder( DB_PATH )
        .setConfig( bolt.type, "BOLT" )
        .setConfig( bolt.enabled, "true" )
        .setConfig( bolt.address, "localhost:7687" )
        .newGraphDatabase();
```

You also have to add the lib in your project :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-bolt</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.5</version>
  </dependency>
```

For more info, see the documentation : https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/tutorials-java-embedded/#tutorials-java-embedded-bolt

Comment: This should indeed work but for some reason doesn't.
Though I get this error from neo4j desktop:
Unable to establish remote connection: Database is unreachable with specified configuration
I do get a "not a WebSocket handshake request: missing upgrade" if I attempt to connect from a browser so the connection is open but the database desktop application is still unable to connect...

Comment: are you on the same host ? Or is it distant ?

Comment: It is the same host (localhost) used during the development process.